# Finding Remainder when N is divided by 99.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Consider the number $N = 1222233333333344\cdots$ (1000 digits). Find the remainder when $N$ is divided by $99$.

MY WORK :-
for a number to be divisible by 99 it must be divisible by 9 and 11.
for $N$ to be divisible by 9, the sum must be divisible by 9; and the sum of all the digits is :
$$1 * 1 + 2 * 4 + 3 * 9 + \cdots = 
                         1 + 8 + 27 +\cdots$$
Basically sum of cubes.

Comment: [sum of cubes](https://www.math-only-math.com/sum-of-the-cubes-of-first-n-natural-numbers.html)

Comment: but that's not working @mathcounterexamples.net ; we are talking it for granted that the remainder is 0, which is not the case.

Comment: after a while, does the digits of $N$ repeats such that we have $1010\ldots10$ followed by $11\ldots11$ and $1212\ldots12$?

Comment: i didn't understand what are trying to imply @SiongThyeGoh ??

Comment: $N$ has $1000$ digits right? each digit $i$ is repeated $i^2$ times? Did I understand the description of $N$ correctly?

Comment: exactly @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: furthermore, some of the repetition of $12$ are being truncated to reach exactly $1000$ digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1. As you say, for a number to be divisible by $9$, the sum of its digits must be divisible by $9$, but actually there is a stronger result: the original number and the sum of the digits have the same remainder when divided by $9$.
2. There is a similar divisibility test for $11$, but it uses the difference between the sums of alternate digits. For example, $6789$ has the same remainder when divided by $11$ as $(9+7)-(8+6)$ does.
3. If you know the remainders when divided by $9$ and $11$, you can deduce the remainder for $99$ (by the Chinese remainder theorem).

Comment: thanks a lot @EspeciallyLime

Answer (score 1):

Complementary hint.

$S_3(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = [S_1(n)]^2 = [\sum_{i=1}^n i]^2.$

The first order of business is to nail down how the sequence ends.

$S_2(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{(n)(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$

Therefore, $S_2(9) = 285.$

Then, you have 100 occurrences of $(10)$ which takes the running total of digits from $285$ to $485.$

Then, you have 121 occurrences of $(11)$ which takes the running total of digits from $485$ to $727$.  This means that the sequence concludes with 136 occurrences of $(12)$, followed by the single digit $1$.

This analysis is needed to utilize Especially Lime's hint/answer.

Comment: thanks a lot @user2661923